# Как в vue.js организовать связь между компонентами?

Tags: javascript, router, vue.js, компоненты

Есть главный компонент и поле для "роутера", содержимое которого меняется в зависимости от url. Я не могу достучаться из компонента роутера к главному компоненту,передать значения и наоборот- с главного в дочерние, находящиеся в поле роутера.
Как вызывать функции и передавать значания в другой компонент vue.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря в какой версии ? 
в версии Vue 1.*

1) `this.$dispatch('someEvent',[params,...]);` - инициировать событие из компонента наверх (всем родителям)

2) `this.$broadcast('someEvent',[params,...]);` - транслировать событие всем потомкам

в самом компоненте перехват события

```
export default {
        data(){},
        events:{
           'someEvent':function([params,...]){}
        }
}
```

В версии Vue 2.* немного иначе, там отказались от всего этого.

Нужно создать еще один экземпляр Vue обычно делается это так:

```
var eventHub = new Vue();

eventHub.$on('test', function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
        eventHub:eventHub
    }
  }
})
```

Далее в любом компоненте в методе можно сделать так:

```
this.$root.eventHub.$emit('test','Тестовое сообщение')
```

Собственно on можно делать внутри компонентов в

```
mounted(){
    var self = this;
    this.$root.eventHub.$on('test',function(){
      //тут используем self для доступа к данным компонента
    })
}
```

Comment: По идее этот ответ уже сильно устарел, разве нет?

Comment: Да, но идея осталась та же, можно использовать eventHub, или передавать событие между компонентами при помощи this.$emit и слушать его в компоненте выше