# как вызвать метод компонента Vue.js по клику?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть компонент модального окна **dialog.vue** из пакета **vue-mdl**

```
<template>
<div class="mdl-dialog-container" v-show="show">
  <div class="mdl-dialog">
    <div class="mdl-dialog__title">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions" :class="actionsClasses">
      <slot name="actions">
        <mdl-button class="mdl-js-ripple-effect" @click.native.stop="close">Close</mdl-button>
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import mdlButton from './button.vue'
import createFocusTrap from 'focus-trap'

export default {
  components: {
    mdlButton
  },

  computed: {
    actionsClasses () {
      return {
        'mdl-dialog__actions--full-width': this.fullWidth
      }
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },

  props: {
    title: {
      type: String
    },
    fullWidth: Boolean
  },

  mounted () {
    this._focusTrap = createFocusTrap(this.$el)
  },

  methods: {
    open () {
      this.show = true
      this.$nextTick(() => this._focusTrap.activate())
      this.$emit('open')
    },
    close () {
      this.show = false
      this._focusTrap.deactivate()
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Я хочу вызвать это окно в другом компоненте

```
<mdl-dialog></mdl-dialog>
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised">Click me</button>
```

Не нашел информации о том, как вызвать метод одного компонента внутри другого. Все примеры, в основном, используют props. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Один из способов по событию, как с ними работать, я только что описал тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-vue-js-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/609312#609312

Comment: Здравствуйте! Если компоненты не связаны иерархически (родитель - потомок), то можно использовать шину событий https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Коммуникация-между-компонентами-не-связанными-иерархически